# How to delete all instances of the image using REST API

Tags: rest-api

When I post an image to WordPress, it is reproduced automatically to multiple images of different sizes.

For example, when I upload `image1.png`, it is uploaded as multiple images as such:

```
image1.png         (Original)

image1-167x93.png  (Resized)

image1-340x180.png (Resized)

image1-600x300.png (Resized)
```

etc..

I am trying to delete `image1.png` through REST API, however, all the resized images remain in the server. Is there a way to delete `image1.png` and all its child images.

To delete `image1.png`, I issue a `DELETE` request using REST API as such:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/<imageid>?force=True
```

Please help how to accomplish the above programmatically, preferably via REST API.

###SOLUTION
I was able to resolve the issue by adding force_delete for all wp_delete_attachment functions inside DeleteImagesManager.php.

Hence changed this function:

wp_delete_attachment($imageId)

to this:

wp_delete_attachment($imageId,$force_delete = true)

Comment: Is everything updated? I just tested this using a quick install of WordPress and it is removing all image sizes related to the ID.

Comment: It's the latest wp version

Comment: You may want to check file permissions then.

Comment: The featured media field is a custom post type. Might have to do with the way the theme  developer hooked up the rest api. However he is refusing to assist in rest api matters. Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm, are you deleting the post as well?

Comment: Yes I'm deleting the post then im deleting the image

Comment: Maybe there's a way using wp cli interface?I considered ftp but it's too slow and not programmatic friendly

Comment: CLI would handle it as well - wp post delete --force $(wp post list --post_type='attachment' --format=ids)

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/list/

Comment: I've also used this - https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-cleaner/ though the pro version adds to the CLI

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. :)

Comment: are you trying to delete an attachment that shows in the standard media library that represents image1.png? ( and by proxy also deleting the file? ) Or is this a custom post type? When you make your REST API request, what happens? Usually the REST API will tell you why it failed if it fails, but I see no details in your question about what the response looked like.

Comment: Also, if the original is deleted but the resized images are not, that sounds like a server permissions related issue, not a PHP issue. I do not believe it is something that we or your themes author can help with, your host may be able to help, and you may be able to fix it yourself with an FTP client or SSH access by fixing the ownership and permissions of the files and the folder itself. IMO this is possibly a localised server issue, not a WordPress issue

Comment: the delete request returns 200 (success), and result is that image is deleted successfully but without the resized images. I'm not getting any other useful information.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by adding force_delete in the DeleteImagesManager.php inside the wp_delete_attachment function. Hence as follows: wp_delete_attachment($imageId,$force_delete = true). There was 2 such functions in the file that were amended accordingly.